# Probability Model For Golf Scores

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to develop a model to simulate future rounds of golf based on past scores for an amateur golf league. My current method is to calculate the weighted average and standard deviation of recent rounds (let's say the last 10 rounds). It's quite easy to generate random values from that. However, in reality amateur golf scores do not appear to follow a normal distribution. The scores tend to bunch up on the low end with a few scores scattered up high. In other words, is easy to shoot slightly below your average, and relatively easy to shoot way above your average, but it's nearly impossible to shoot way below your average. What would be a good model to use to generate scores from this type of data?